# CMD command to move file from one folder to another based on condition

Tags: windows, cmd, directory

I have list of files in a folder A, I need to move the files from folder A to folder B using command prompt with some condition check. Each file named in the following format like,

```
100.abc.docx
102.abx.docx
111.asf.docx
```

I have a list contains the numbers say,

```
101
102
```

I need to move the files starting with this list of numbers to the folder B

So the result will have to be like this,

```
Folder A>> 111.asf.docx

Folder B >>   
100.abc.docx
102.abx.docx
```

How can i use CMD command to do the same, please help..

Answer (score 0):

Try do a batch file to loop your file list and copy file* to your location

```
  for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do move %%A* c:\my\location
```

thanks Stephan, I correct it